# NSMenuItem's NSView not highlighting in submenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, nsmenuitem

I have an `NSStatusItem` that displays an `NSMenu` full of `NSView` subclasses. I override `drawRect:` in my `NSView` subclass to implement highlighting in the `NSMenu` and everything works fine in the root menu, but for some reason it doesn't work in submenus of the root menu. I put some `NSLog` statements in my `NSView` subclasses `drawRect:` and noticed that it's not even being called for the views in the submenu. Any ideas?

I can post the code that I'm using to highlight the views, but I don't think that its necessary since `drawRect:` is not even being called. Let me know if there's any other code you need to see that might help.

Comment: Did you connect the NSView subclasses to the submenus view?

Comment: Yes `mouseDown:` is still called when I click on the NSView's in the submenu, but `drawRect:` isn't being called.

Comment: Are your subviews set with `NSMenuItem`'s `setView:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have resolved itself. I might have just forgot to set the view to use my `NSView` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use NSMenuItem's setEnabled method to sort of jog the submenuItems awake?

Comment: Just tried that. `drawRect:` is still not being called for the items in the submenu.